# Getting error in Paytm Payment Gateway while uploading app on appstore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, payment, paytm

Getting **Module compiled with Swift  5.0.1 can not be imported by swift 5.1** error while i have added PaymentSDK Swift5. Then i tried PaymentSDK 5.1 framework not getting this error while uploading app to AppStore. Working perfectly on development mode.

Applied this solution

1. https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit/issues/37#issuecomment-533982199
2. https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit/issues/40#issuecomment-538249618

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly mentioned about you are uploading with simulator framework, during upload your framework should not contain simulator frameworks `x86_64, i386`. When you do uploading add shell script that removes that architecture from release builds. Use this script in the build phase script.[remove simulator architectures](https://gist.github.com/Bengejd/df5dbbd807b5822761194d601149b86d)

Comment: Already tried this solution https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit/issues/37#issuecomment-533982199

Comment: If you tried this then it should not give you this error anymore. Should be something diff

Comment: Can you check what is architecture of your framework by using lipo -info framework binary

Comment: let me try your solution.

Comment: Can you check what’s the arch info by using lipo -info command?

Comment: I don't know how do that.

Comment: Open terminal and write lipo -info your binary path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200817/discussion-between-pramod-tapaniya-and-shauket-sheikh).

Answer (score 0):

```
         Copy PaymentsSDK.framework in your Mac’s Downloads folder.
    
       // Open Terminal and move to the Downloads folder of your mac.
          cd /Users/<Your Mac's User Name Here>/Downloads
       //Run these commands to strip the x86_64 and i386 builds from your binary.
         
        lipo -remove x86_64 PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK -o 
          PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK
     
         lipo -remove i386 PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK -o 
          PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK
    
     //That’s it. Now you have stripped out all the unnecessary builds from your //binary.
    Now-Again. Copy Payments.sdk from your Downloads folder and replace it from the previous binary.

// Now, it will be validated successfully without any issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate the latest SDK for iOS. The Github link for the SDK is https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_iOS_All_in_One_SDK. Its integration information is available on developer docs of Paytm.